# move_uploaded_file reported that I haven't permission to move (PHP)

Tags: php, file-upload, permissions, apache2, chmod

I have a script that handle uploading some files in "upload" directory.

So, in case of uploading I got that error:

```
move_uploaded_file(/var/www/some_dir/upload/8phMPmnoXOI.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

my apache2 runs under www-data user (OS ubuntu linux).

```
#id www-data 
uid=33(www-data) gid=1000(ubuntu) groups=1000(ubuntu),33(www-data)

#ls -la | grep upload
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr 29 18:30 upload
```

If I try to "touch" new file into this directory it works!

**Why I can't write to writeable directory?**

P.S. `chmod -R 777 upload` resolves that problem, but I want to ubuntu:ubuntu owns upload directory.

Comment: `chown ubuntu:ubuntu /var/www/some_dir/upload` to change ownership of the **upload** directory to the user **ubuntu**. Also, the www-data user requires access to the file, not just the directory.

Comment: But file doesn't exist yet!